Dynamic toolbar won't appear in Eclipse RCP app
I built an RCP app with java 17 and Eclipse 2024.06 using Maven Tycho plugin 4.0.8.
In plugin.xml I defined a toolbar.
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
            <toolbar id="com.company.project.ui.admin.zone.toolbar">
                <dynamic
                        class="com.company.project.ui.admin.zone.editor.util.SelectZonesDropDownContributionItem"
                        id="com.company.project.ui.admin.zone_selector_contribution">
                    <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
                        <with variable="activeEditorId">
                            <equals value="com.company.project.client.editors.zone"></equals>
                        </with>
                    </visibleWhen>
                </dynamic>
            </toolbar>
        </menuContribution>
    </extension>
</plugin>

I expect the toolbar to be appeared in my app but nothing happens, there is just empty space on the toolbar where my dropdowns should be located.
In the past, the application had been built with Eclipse Mars (using Eclipse Product export wizard) and Java 8 and it worked. Recently I updated the Eclipse framework and started to use Tycho to build the app.
Please let me know if any information needed to understand the problem better.
UPD: The reproducible example might be found here here
UPD2: The exception I get when toolbar is created:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2024-09-30 15:15:17.998
!MESSAGE Loaded class is of incorrect type: expected(org.eclipse.ui.menus.WorkbenchWindowControlContribution) got (com.company.project.ui.admin.zone.editor.util.SelectZonesDropDownContributionItem)
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Loaded class is of incorrect type: expected(org.eclipse.ui.menus.WorkbenchWindowControlContribution) got (com.company.project.ui.admin.zone.editor.util.SelectZonesDropDownContributionItem)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.util.Util.safeLoadExecutableExtension(Util.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.menus.CompatibilityWorkbenchWindowControlContribution.construct(CompatibilityWorkbenchWindowControlContribution.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolControlContribution.createControl(ToolControlContribution.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.updateWidget(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer.subscribeUIElementTopicVisible(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:219)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4814)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.DisplayUISynchronize.syncExec(DisplayUISynchronize.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setVisible(UIElementImpl.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarContributionRecord.updateVisibility(ToolBarContributionRecord.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer$2.changed(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActiveEditorSources(WorkbenchPage.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPage.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partBroughtToTop(WorkbenchPage.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$6.run(PartServiceImpl.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartBroughtToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.lambda$0(PartServiceImpl.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4814)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.DisplayUISynchronize.syncExec(DisplayUISynchronize.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3228)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$11(WorkbenchPage.java:3118)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3086)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3069)
    at com.company.project.ui.admin.zone.command.EditZonesCommand.execute(EditZonesCommand.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:98)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at com.company.project.ui.admin.view.NavigationTreeClickListener.launchMap(NavigationTreeClickListener.java:503)
    at com.company.project.ui.admin.view.NavigationTreeClickListener.doubleClick(NavigationTreeClickListener.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1205)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:173)
    at com.company.project.ui.admin.Application.start(Application.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1481)


Is SelectZonesDropDownContributionItem being called? Does it work without the visibleWhen?

Hi Greg! No, I tried to set a few breakpoints in overridden methods but non of them hit when I build it with Eclispe 2024.06 and Java 17. Also, I tried to remove visibleWhen but it didn't change anything. However, SelectZonesDropDownContributionItem default constructor and its parent consturctors are being executed. But overriden getContributionItems() and fill() methods won't be executed. I took two screenshots https://i.ibb.co/tqL0QHN/Screenshot-1.jpg and https://i.ibb.co/BLMGpRS/Screenshot-2.jpg . The 2nd one shows that "empty space" I mentioned in my initial post.

Sorry, this is my fault, I didn't see an exception in the logs. I believe it might help to understand the problem. Also, I tried to create a new project and got the same exception. So now I have a reproducible example. Please see it on my github.  https://github.com/IvanSeregin/DynamicMenu

I updated my post and added the exception and link to MRE.

Code you want us to look at must be in the question. Looks like your class doesn't extend WorkbenchWindowControlContribution which is mandatory
